# Как запустить 2 или более функций при нажатии одной кнопки PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5

Возможно ли, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку выполнялись две функции? Прошу Вашей помощи!

Вот мой класс окна:

```
class Window_3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_regit()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton3.clicked.connect(self.go_end)
        self.ui.pushButton4.clicked.connect(self.processor) #  хочу вызвать processor и matherboard

    def go_end(self):
        self.hide()

    def processor(self):
        name_proc = "ProcessorNameString"
        n_p = True
        with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
            with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0") as sub_key:
                try:
                    i = 0
                    while n_p:
                        path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                        if name_proc == path_value[0]:
                            self.ui.label_proc_info.setText(f"{path_value[1]}")
                            print(f"Proseccor: {path_value[1]}")
                            n_p = False
                        else:
                            i += 1
                except OSError:
                    print("processor not found")
            winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
        winreg.CloseKey(hkey)

    def matherboard(self):
        name_proc = "BaseBoardproduct"
        n_p = True
        with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as hkey:
            with winreg.OpenKey(hkey, "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS\\0") as sub_key:
                try:
                    i = 0
                    while n_p:
                        path_value = winreg.EnumValue(sub_key, i)
                        if name_proc == path_value[0]:
                            self.ui.label_proc_info_2.setText(f"{path_value[1]}")
                            n_p = False
                        else:
                            i += 1
                except OSError:
                    pass
            winreg.CloseKey(sub_key)
        winreg.CloseKey(hkey)
```

Comment: Так они параллельно должны выполниться, или последовательно?

Comment: последовательно

Comment: Объясните  пожалуйста лучше, какая у вас проблема. У вас есть трудности вызвать один метод из другого метода или у вас проблема в чем-то другом?

Comment: хотел чтоб при нажатии на кнопку вызывались 2 метода

Comment: arnold если вы пишите, что методы выполниться последовательно, то вызываете первый метод, после его завершения и анализа его результатов (если это необходимо) вызываете из первого метода второй метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать connect второй раз

```
self.ui.pushButton4.clicked.connect(self.processor)
self.ui.pushButton4.clicked.connect(self.matherboard)
```